# SEO Friendly URLs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Working on a project with Laravel 5.2 and just trying to implement SEO friendly urls and remove the id aspect from the url itself.

Usually you would do something like this:

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostsController');
```

where you would have in url "www.mywebsite.com/post/12" - the id of the post
now if i replace that to its title, in my controller I have to now search by their title in the database. If there are two posts with the same title i get an error since it is finding more then one record

So my question is, how do I allow the same title in posts to be used along with SEO friendly url and still search by id or something along those lines in the controller show method.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: since the title is now effectively the id, you have to enforce that every title is unique. you have no other choice. otherwise it is literally impossible to say that `example.com/article/himom` points to your recipe for fabulous fajitas, while the exact same `example.com/article/himom` points to your heartfealt mother's day greeting.

Comment: I know what you mean, but is there any way to make it so I can allow users to post the article with the same title?

Comment: I would add a new field to your table called slug and use that as the unique field.  Then you can have same titles but different slugs.

Comment: @max234435 Look into https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Comment: let them post whatever you want, but if the title gets reduced down to something that already exists, then you'll have to enforce SOMETHING different about it, e.g. add an id, start a counter, etc...

Comment: I see what you guys mean, I'll take a look at the article @ceejayoz. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can add a `unique` column called `slug` to your database table.

One approach to this would be to make the column `nullable` and then generate the slug after the `Post` has been created.

In your `Post` model add the following:

```
/**
 * Boot the model
 */
public static function boot()
{
    static::created(function ($post) {

        $post->generateSlug();

    });
}

/**
 * Generate the slug for the newly created Post
 */
protected function generateSlug()
{
    $slug = str_slug($this->slug);

    if (static::slug($slug)->exists()) {
        $slug .= '-' . $this->id;
    }

    $this->slug = $slug;
    $this->save();
}

/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

/**
 * Constrain the query to the provided slug
 *
 * @param $query
 * @param $slug
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopeSlug($query, $slug)
{
    return $query->where('slug', $slug);
}
```

So, once the `Post` is created the `generateSlug` method is called. This will make a slug out of the title of the `Post`. It will then just do a quick check to see if a `Post` already has that slug and it so it will just append the `id` of the `Post` to the end of it. It will then save it.
The `getRouteKeyName` method just means that with your `Route::resource` Laravel will automatically use the `slug` field rather than the `id` to resolve model.

Obviously, feel free to change how you make the `slug` unique, I've just used the `id` as it's a simple example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is wrong approach. What if someone wants to change the slug? This happens often with articles / blog posts. URL with the previous slug will result in 404 error.

Comment: @emix As mentioned in the answer, this is just one approach. The OP's question was about creating unique slugs not how to track and have their app handle url changes, and since the question didn't mention anything like that I would argue that adding that to the answer would be out of scope for the question. I would say that it's not the *wrong* approach at all, SO is not the place to come to for a complete solution, it's a place to get help with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the id in the url and change the route with id and slug so that if you have any link which has id will be redirected to corresponding proper url with slug.

You can read [this article](https://medium.com/@bigbharatjain/how-to-create-non-breaking-seo-friendly-urls-in-laravel-42daccdc5f85) to have some detailed idea.
Sites like Stackoverflow, medium etc. follow the similar thing to make the URL SEO friendly.